# Access another mailbox calendar events with PHP-EWS

Tags: php, calendar, exchangewebservices, php-ews

In PHP-EWS library (https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) I can access the calendar events of a specific user using this code: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki/Calendar:-Get-List-(Retrieving-Id-and-ChangeKey)
In all the library features we always use the authentication for a single user:

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host, $username, $password, $version);
```

However how can I get the calendar events from another user's mailbox? If I have an account in LDAP with admin privileges is it possible to access the calendar events from another user mailbox using the PHP-EWS library? Or is it only possible to access the mailbox of the user account credentials used in the authentication?

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host, $username, $password, $version);
```

Does anyone have an example to access the calendar events from another user mailbox using the PHP-EWS library with an LDAP admin account?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to try posting this question to the github issues page for the project: [https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/issues](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/issues).

Answer (score 2):

In the code block under *Only look in the "calendars folder"* add this in order to retrieve events from email@address.com's calendar:

```
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Mailbox = new StdClass;
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Mailbox->EmailAddress = 'email@address.com';
```