# PHP and Exchange Web Services: Read email from functional mailbox

Tags: php, email, message, exchangewebservices

I'm using the code below to get the count of messages in the inbox:

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($mailserver, $mailuser, $mailpass, ExchangeWebServices::VERSION_2010);

$request = new EWSType_FindItemType();
$itemProperties = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$itemProperties->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::ID_ONLY;
$itemProperties->BodyType = EWSType_BodyTypeResponseType::BEST;
$request->ItemShape = $itemProperties;

$fieldType = new EWSType_PathToUnindexedFieldType();
$fieldType->FieldURI = 'message:IsRead';

$constant = new EWSType_FieldURIOrConstantType();
$constant->Constant = new EWSType_ConstantValueType();
$constant->Constant->Value = "0";

$IsEqTo = new EWSType_IsEqualToType();
$IsEqTo->FieldURIOrConstant = $constant;
$IsEqTo->Path = $fieldType;

$request->Restriction = new EWSType_RestrictionType();
$request->Restriction->IsEqualTo = new EWSType_IsEqualToType();
$request->Restriction->IsEqualTo->FieldURI = $fieldType;
$request->Restriction->IsEqualTo->FieldURIOrConstant = $constant;

$request->IndexedPageItemView = new EWSType_IndexedPageViewType();
$request->IndexedPageItemView->BasePoint = 'Beginning';
$request->IndexedPageItemView->Offset = 0;

$request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::INBOX;

$request->Traversal = EWSType_ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;

$result = new EWSType_FindItemResponseMessageType();
$result = $ews->FindItem($request);

if ($result->ResponseMessages->FindItemResponseMessage->ResponseCode == 'NoError' && $result->ResponseMessages->FindItemResponseMessage->ResponseClass == 'Success'){

    $count = $result->ResponseMessages->FindItemResponseMessage->RootFolder->TotalItemsInView;

    if($count > 0) {
        echo $count . " email(s)";
    } else {
        echo 'No email(s)';
    }

}
```

The code comes from this question: [PHP and Exchange Web Services : fetching the message body using php-ews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300863/php-and-exchange-web-services-fetching-the-message-body-using-php-ews)

Is there any way to use this code to fetch email from another mailbox that I have permission to access, like a functional mailbox?

**Solution**

Sorry, I just found this: [Access another mailbox calendar events with PHP-EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275060/access-another-mailbox-calendar-events-with-php-ews)

```
$request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Mailbox = new StdClass;
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Mailbox->EmailAddress = 'email@domain.com';
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::INBOX;
```

It helped me, case closed!